# Call the data-list in Thunkable

Tags: json, expandablelistview, thunkable

I want to call or retrieve the same data once I click on one of the list view items.
in another word, whenever I click on any of the item listed in the listview, I need that list to expand for me showing the same results of its call. What should i put in the **List_viwer2** call function?

[image: here is my code. the last part i need to solve.]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a screen, and drag a label.

Then add this code in Screen1:

```
initialize app variable clicked_option
```

And inside the List_Viewer block:

```
set clicked_option to item
```

Then in Screen2:

```
when Screen2 opens

set [label name] to clicked_option
```